# AccessoryDetailDisclosureButton action

Tags: uitableview

I have added a custom UIButton on each table view cell of a table. And I am assigning this button to AccessoryDetailDisclosureButton. So in a nut shell, its a custom AccessoryDetailDisclosureButton. This is how I am doing it in cellforrowatindexpath:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] ;
    UIButton *ACC = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    ACC.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 25, 25);
    if(iPhone)
    {
        [ACC setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"select_arrow.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    else
    {
        ACC.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 60);

        [ACC setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"select_arrow@2x.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
    cell.accessoryView = ACC;
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
}
```

Now the thing is,
I want to put same action on AccessoryDetailDisclosureButton which is in didSelectRowAtIndexPath
I would write body of didSelectRowAtIndexPath in accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath method but it won't work.

Now if I comment cell.accessoryView = ACC; in above code. it would work fine. but I can't remove the image from the accessory button

How can I get rid of it.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a target and selector to your button.

```
[ACC addTarget:self action:@selector(handleRowSelection:)
     forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

That being said, you should refrain from introducing new UI elements that do not add functionality.